# How to pass value from C++ class constructor as a default argment of method of this class?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to build some program in C++, but I'm quite newbie in OOP and I meet a problem that Google can't help me for right now. I think that the C++ is in version 14, but I'm still not sure how to check this in VS2017. I want to use thevalues passed to the class' constructor as default values for another method of the same class.

Specially for my problem I build simple case program for adding two int's, which is in three separate files and it looks like this:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add_this.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Add plus(1, 2);
   cout << plus.AddingResult(IF EMPTY, TAKE VALS 1 AND 2 FROM ABOVE plus) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

*add_this.cpp*

```
#include "add_this.h"
Add::Add(int a, int b)
{
}
Add::~Add()
{
}
int Add::AddingResult(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

*add_this.h*

```
#pragma once
class Add
{
    private:
        int a;
        int b;
    public:
        Add(int a, int b);
        ~Add();
        int AddingResult(int a, int b);
};
```

Ok, if in main.cpp I pass values by hand in example `plus.AddingResult(2, 3)` I will get 5. My problem is that I want to get method, which will take `b` or `a` and `b` values (or in super method version will take `b` by hand and pass `a` from constructor). I try a lot of approaches related with pointers or defining Set and Get methods but all fails in my implementation - I don't say that they are wrong I say that my implementations was wrong. I wont attache them for question clarity.

Comment: Why not simply create 3 classes: for 0 default value, for 1 default value, for 2 default values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's give your identifiers better names:

```
class Adder
{
    int lhs_;
    int rhs_;
public:
    Adder(int lhs, int rhs);
    ~Adder();
```

Then we define an [overload set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) for the member function `add` as we cannot define arguments with non-static member variable as their default value:

```
    int add(int lhs, int rhs);
    int add(int lhs);
    int add();
};
```

Then, we need to "save" the values given to `Adder`'s constructor:

```
Adder::Adder(int lhs, int rhs)
: lhs_(lhs), rhs_(rhs) // 1
{}
```

The line marked `// 1` is the syntax for the [member-initializer-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list); it initializes the member variables `lhs_` and `rhs_` with the argument's values. Last step, we use those variables in our overload set:

```
int Adder::add(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}
int Adder::add(int lhs)
{
    return add(lhs, rhs_);
}
int Adder::add()
{
    return add(lhs_, rhs_);
}
```

Full demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e08b8860c20d53c9

Comment: It works, thank You! Now I can to implement this to bigger program :) I have additional question on that problem. What if we have **N** parameters in adder - is there some systematic/general approach for such kind of problem?

Comment: @mimi yes, lookup `std::vector` and parameter packs. If you have quetsions about them, and those questions qualify as on-topic on SO, please ask another SO question.

Comment: Ok, thank you, good hint about `std::vector` in this place. I asked just because of I'm was curious about that - if it will be bigger problem I will ask another question on SO.